# Why can't you not always avoid select in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, find

There is quite [a popular question on avoiding select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), but that does not always seem to work, as you can see from this example:

There is a question about somebody, trying to find something on an Excel sheet, so I decided to help.
First I selected some cells and launched a `Find`, everything was working fine, so I recorded this as a VBA macro:

```
Range("B1:B10").Select

Selection.Find(What:="test", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Then, as usual, I removed the `Select`, turning my macro into this:

```
Range("B1:B10").Find(What:="test", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

To my surprise, this yielded a `Type Mismatch` error.

Why is that?
And what about avoiding the "Select" in VBA? Are there more such cases where this is not possible?

Comment: `After:=ActiveCell` should be `After:=Range("B1")`

Comment: @ScottCraner: you're right: when I select cell "B1" before launching my macro, everything is working fine. In other words: the `After` must be a single cell, which is part of the search area.

Comment: @BigBen: thanks, I adopted my comment.